# Modes, Address-spaces and Contexts

Tags: operating-system

When reading OS books we frequently encounter terms like user-mode, kernel-mode, user-space, kernel-space, process context and interrupt/system context. How can they be precisely defined? I guess they cannot be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

User mode: where a process has limited freedom to perform actions. process is not able to perform actions which can effect whole system or other processes. 
such actions/operations are called privileged operations e.g. assigning memory to process.

kernel mode: the privilege operations which a process can not perform, kernel do it on behalf of that process. when kernel is requested to perform privilege operation, the process is said to be in kernel mode.

user space: inerchangeably used with user mode. it represents the structures/assets solely belong to process.

kernel space: interchang ably used for kernel mode.

context: in which mode is processing executing is called context i.e kernel context or process context.

interrupt: an event to tell the kernel that something important has happened which needs your(kernel) attention

system context: means kernel context.

Answer (score 0):

These cannot be precisely defined because the terms can be used differently, depending upon the system in question.

One of your concepts is the division of the logical address space. Most systems using virtual/logical memory divide the address space in some way. In some cases the division is in hardware. In others it is done in software.

It is common to divide the full logical address space into two regions. One of these regions is the kernel [address] space. This is a region in memory that is shared by all processes in the system. If a process changes a memory value in the kernel space, every process sees that change. The other common region is the user [address] space. This range of addresses is duplicated for every process on the system. If a process changes a memory value in the user space, no other process sees that change (NOTE: This is a general rule. Most system have memory sharing mechanisms).

The address range assigned to system and user spaces varies among systems. Also, some systems have additional address spaces used for other purposes.

Because a process can change a value in the system space and have every other process see that change, there is a security issue. The solution used is to have different processor modes and access to memory restricted by mode. The most common processor modes are user (the normal operating mode of a process) and kernel (used for system processing).

When the process is in user mode, it cannot mess with kernel mode data (and usually cannot even read it). When it is Kernel mode it can usually read and write everything.

Some processors have additional modes. The VAX has four modes.

There are three ways a processor can move from user move from user mode to kernel mode.

1) Fault. A fault is an exception that is restartable. A page fault is an example. The user accesses a page that is not in memory. That triggers a page fault. The system maps the page needed. Then it restarts the instruction that caused the fault. Debuggers use faults to trigger breakpoints.

2) Trap. A trap is like a fault but it is it not restartable. For example, divide by zero might be implemented as a trap (a system might implement it as  a fault as well). There are special trap instructions that are used to explicitly enter kernel mode to use system services (e.g., for the process to perform I/O).

3) Interrupt. An interrupt is external event that causes the processor to go into kernel mode. Examples include a timer going off and a device needing attention (e.g., someone pressed a key on the keyboard).

Generally, processors handle all three of these situations the same way (unless you are in Intel-land). Also, Intel documentation calls all three of these "Interrupts".

The process context is the machine state of a process. Usually processors have load process context and save process context instructions that do this in one step. To switch processes, the system does a save, then a load of a new process.

I have tried to give you the general meanings here as well as some variants to illustrate why there is no precise definition of the terms ask about.

Answer (score 0):

Classifying the terms under the module where they are used would help in understanding them better.

---

### Threads

Threads in an operating system have with them an associated *thread access mode*. The idea is about what privileges does a thread have? There are two types of thread access modes -

- **User Mode:**

  1. Allows access to non-operating system code and data only
  2. Does not allow any access to hardware
  3. If a thread crashes here, it will only crash its parent application at worst.
- **Kernel Mode:**

  1. It is a privileged mode for use by the kernel and device drivers only

     1. Sometimes a user mode thread change its status to kernel mode to perform get the privileges associated with kernel mode
  2. Allows access to all the resources of the system - any memory location, hard drive.. anything
  3. If a thread crashes here, it is catastrophic and results in the Blue Screen Of Death

---

### Memory

Operating system has a mapping of physical addresses stored in *virtual addresses*. Hence using virtual addresses, the OS can access the actual locations on Memory. We need exclusive space for kernel mode thread executions. Goes without saying that kernel mode threads only are allowed to use this piece of memory and this section of memory is aptly named **Kernel space**. Whatever in the memory is not kernel space, is classified as **User space**.

This usage is memory is so important that when you want your threads from different processes to interact, you have to use separate common block of memory which they both can access instead of letting one thread to peek into another thread's address space.

---

### Process

In order to run the instructions of a process or even a thread within a process, the CPU has to know some *things* about it. These *things* are collectively called the context.

When you schedule a process/thread for execution on a CPU, the CPU has to know the values in the registers when last time this process/thread was executing. The entire step of loading a process/thread's information in the CPU is called **Context Switch.**

---

### Interrupts

Interrupts and their different types are fairly easy to understand from their [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) itself:

> An interrupt is a signal to the processor emitted by hardware or
>   software indicating an event that needs immediate attention. An
>   interrupt alerts the processor to a high-priority condition requiring
>   the interruption of the current code the processor is executing. The
>   processor responds by suspending its current activities, saving its
>   state, and executing a function called an interrupt handler (or an
>   interrupt service routine, ISR) to deal with the event. This
>   interruption is temporary, and, after the interrupt handler finishes,
>   the processor resumes normal activities.